# HTML with PHP not working

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm using Apache as a server,
my index.php code is

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<my HTML code>
<?php
wait_file:{
        // Do something to receive file.
    }
    else
    {
        goto wait_file;
    }
}

detect_file:{
    if(file_exists($file))
    {
        // do something with received file.
    }
    else
    {
        goto detect_file;
    }
}
?>
</html>
```

but when I visit index.php ,
the webpage is always loading,
and my background picture doesn't show(it may means HTML code are not working),
I think the key point is that i used "goto",made the if-loop to wait for file,
but i don't know how to slove it .

Comment: what do you mean? be more specific. I don't know If you actually do even understand your problem

Comment: If by `is always loading` you mean it does *not stop loading*, then your PHP code is your problem and *not* HTML.

Comment: my index.php is blank,I guess that my html code are not working.

Comment: do you know how to solve it ? I need the PHP part,and i can't let the page blank :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this code, there is actually not much that could work. I don't
   know where `$file` could come from, it looks like it's undefined so
   your goto will result in an infinite loop.
2. Then you have to have an `if` to use `else`.
3. There is no output because of the infinite loop, so it is blank while loading. And I can't even see what the page should show because I don't know whats behind `<my HTML code>`. There is no output in the code you've posted.

Comment: I set php part as a wait-loop ,waiting for a file i send from another device,i have tested it,it's done well.

but when i add HTML, it still just wait,not show my background,tittle...etc.
I need both of them ,how can i display my appearance by HTML and wait for file at the same time?

Comment: just a background photo ,and a button to next page  in my HTML code

Comment: You are mixing server side code with client side code. PHP is running on the server and once finished the HTML is sent to the client. You could check for the file using `AJAX` requests with `setInterval` in Javascript.

Comment: You mean that I have to receive file with AJAX,cause it's asynchrony,so I can avoid the infinite loop?

Comment: Exactly. The other way you will not receive anything till the file is available.